# smtp Hotmail settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
MailMessage mail = new 
MailMessage(txtEmail,"taqi.shemaz@hotmail.com",txtSubject,txtMessage);
SmtpServer.Port = 587;       
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("taqi.shemaz@hotmail.com", "******");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Here `txtEmail` is the sender Email address which I need to get in the my inbox as email from:

> From: Raj (Raj@yahoo.com)
>   Sent:   Thursday, August 13, 2015 1:32:36 PM
>   To: taqi.shemaz@hotmail.com

But problem is I am getting from email and to email the same "taqi.shemaz@hotmail.com"

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the address of "from" and send it as first argument, like this:

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("Raj@yahoo.com","taqi.shemaz@hotmail.com",txtSubject,txtMessage);
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("taqi.shemaz@hotmail.com", "******");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

The separation can be done with various manipulations on text, might be even something trivial (if the text is always in the format you mentioned above) like this:

```
        int startInd = txtEmail.IndexOf("(");
        int len = txtEmail.IndexOf(")") - txtEmail.IndexOf("(");
        string senderEmail = txtEmail.Substring(startInd, len);
```

If you need more help, let me know

Comment: That is he doing with `txtEmail,"taqi.shemaz@hotmail.com"`or?

Comment: MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(senderEmail,"taqi.shemaz@hotmail.com",txtSubject,txtMessage);

Comment: if he uses the "separator" that I wrote

Comment: txtEmail => raj@yahoo.com Which is my sender Email ID

Comment: I posted a code that extracts just the email (raj@yahoo.com in your example) and then you can use it like this:
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(senderEmail,"taqi.shemaz@hotmail.com",txtSubject,txtMessage);